# Basis reduction and continued fractions

Tags: discrete-mathematics, integer-lattices

While reading several articles about lattice basis reduction I am left with a few questions.

For one, I came across this piece of text

> Let $\alpha$ and $\beta \in \mathbb{R}$. Then there are two almost the same ways to compute small values for $\alpha x + \beta y$ with not too large $x,y \in \mathbb{Z}$.
>
> 1) applying the continued fraction algorithm
>
> 2) Applying the lattice basis reduction algorithm to the lattice generated by the columns of the matrix
>
> \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ C\alpha & C\beta \end{pmatrix}
>   for $C$ large enough.

Why are those (for me different algorithms) in the above sense the same?

And also, where is the $C$ coming from? When is it large enough? It obviously depends on something...

All hints, examples or explanations are very much welcome.

Answer (score 1):

W.l.o.g. you can scale the matrix, and get the equivalent problem of reducing the matrix $\pmatrix{\epsilon & 0 \cr a & b}$ for tiny $\epsilon$. Now it is easy to see that for sufficiently small $\epsilon$ each step of the basis reduction algorithm changes $(a, b)$ exactly as one step of the GCD algorithm. From the size of the intermediate quantities you can infer how small $\epsilon$ must be.